# How do I escape the ERB tag in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, erb, fixture

I have a simple `fixture.yml` file:

```
label:
    body: "<%= variable %>"
```

The issue is that the ERB code is parsed as part of loading the fixture, whereas I actually want the body to be literally "<%= variable %>" (un-interpolated).

How do I escape the ERB tag?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Add a second `%` to the opening tag:

```
label:
    body: "<%%= variable %>"
```

The `<%%` sequence is [valid ERB](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html), rendered as a literal `<%`.

Comment: ah ha!  I was doubling both of them! TY

Comment: This would be what you would use to print out an erb-style JST (ie underscore)  within a a rails erb file.