# I dump data to a yml file, but can't load. Is it a "to_yaml" bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I dump the data from database to "test/fixtures/*.yml", but when I use `rake db:fixtures:load`, it complains the content of yml is invalid. Following is the content of my yml:

```
answer_00016: 
  id: 16
  content: |-
            <% output_once :define_aaa do %>
                Your stuff here
            <% end %>
```

Notice, the `<% ... %>` part is the content of the answer.

When I load the fixture, the error message is:

```
The exact error was:
  NoMethodError: undefined method `output_once' for main:Object
```

Following is my code to **dump data**:

```
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name)
file.write data.inject({}) {|hash, record|
     hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
     hash
}.to_yaml
```

Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: [How do I escape ERB code in fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-erb-code-in-fixtures)

When I write to file, I should replace `<%` with `<%%` first