# How to dump the database to yaml file with content '<% abc do %>ddd<% end %>'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, fixtures

In my database, there are some text content, one of them is:

```
<% abc do %>
ddd
<% end %>
```

When I dumped it to yaml with `to_yaml()`, it is like:

```
content: |-
    <% abc do %>
    ddd
    <% end %>
```

And then, when I use `rake db:fixtures:load`, such error occurs:

```
The exact error was: 
  NoMethodError: undefined method 'abc' for main:Object
```

I checked the source of `db:fixtures:load`, and found rails will not treat the content as plain text, but `erb` template, so it will try to find and execute the 'abc' method.

How can I fix this? I think the default 'to_yaml' should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can escape the '<%' as:
[How do I escape ERB code in fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-erb-code-in-fixtures)

I'm doing now: before writing to file, I replaced all '<%' with '<%%'. But it is not always work correctly. If the content has some non-English charactor, the content will be dump as 'binary', not text. Then when read back, the '<%%' won't be converted to '<%'.