# Chef ERB template with Logstash Grok pattern issues

Tags: chef-infra, erb, chef-recipe, chef-template

I have a logstash config file that I need to convert to a chef erb template (mainly the filters section). However, I keep running into issues due to the format of the grok patterns. 
Below is an example of the grok pattern.

```
  grok {
    match => ["message", "<%{POSINT:seqnum1}>%{POSINT:seqnum2}: (\d*: |\.|\*)*%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:tz}: \%%{WORD:facility_label}-(%{WORD:switch_id}-)*%{INT:severity}-%{WORD:program}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
```

Here is the issue. Shortly after this I need to have some interpolation fill in an IP address etc. But it wont because the `<%` starts an interpolation of its own.

```
mutate {
  add_field => {"[@metadata][sentry][msg]" => "%{host}"
    "[@metadata][sentry][severity]" => "%{severity}"
    "[@metadata][sentry][host]" => "<%= @sentry_host[:ipaddress] %>"
    "[@metadata][sentry][pid]" => "<%= @sentry_pid %>"
    "[@metadata][sentry][key]" => "<%= @sentry_key %>"
    "[@metadata][sentry][secret]" => "<%= @sentry_secret %>"
  }
}
```

So all of the values above are processed as the string of `<%= @sentry_... %>`.

Is there a way to get around this? I have tried the escape method of `<%%{POSINT:seqnum1}>%{POSINT:seqnum2}:%>` seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-erb-code-in-fixtures). But it still puts the closing `%>` in. Any other ways to escape characters/strings in ERB?

Thanks! 
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to put the `%>` in your text. `<%%` becomes a literal `<%` and it doesn't need a paired ending tag.

EDIT example of `erb -x`:

```
$ echo '<%% foo <%= asdf %> bar <%= baz %>' | erb -x
#coding:ASCII-8BIT
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat "<% foo "; _erbout.concat(( asdf ).to_s); _erbout.concat " bar "; _erbout.concat(( baz ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
```

Comment: Thanks for being on this so quickly! However if I do the <%% it wont interpolate anything until the close/ending "%>" AFTER the "@sentry_host[:ipaddress]"         `"[@metadata][sentry][host]" => "<%= @sentry_host[:ipaddress] %>"
 "[@metadata][sentry][pid]" => "<%= @sentry_host[:ipaddress] %>"` ends up being `       "[@metadata][sentry][host]" => "<%= @sentry_host[:ipaddress] %>"
       "[@metadata][sentry][pid]" => "10.100.100.100"`

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow this in a comment, but you can always pipe a snippet of Erb to `erb -x` to see the generated Ruby code, that should give you an idea of what's going on :)