# Escape character in erb file

Tags: puppet, erb

I am trying to include an erb file in puppet. But the file consists of lines like these:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ww" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="ui" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="webwork" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" uri="sitemesh-page" %>
```

When I run puppet, this is showing a syntax error that says
`'@ '` is not allowed as an instance variable name.

How can I escape this character `@`?

Comment: There's no way to "escape" it in this context, it's just invalid Ruby syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It would be helpful to also include what the rendered file should look like instead of just what an attempted template looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is basically answered here already: [How do I escape the ERB tag in ERB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-the-erb-tag-in-erb).

You can't escape the `@` character per se; you need to "escape" the ERB tags, by using the sequence `<%%` to indicate that you want the literal string `<%`.

So, change your ERB code to:

```
<%%@ taglib prefix="ww" uri="webwork" %>
<%%@ taglib prefix="ui" uri="webwork" %>
<%%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="webwork" %>
<%%@ taglib prefix="page" uri="sitemesh-page" %>
```