# String Interpolation in escaped erb tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, erb, string-interpolation

I have a ERB(database.yml.erb) file template for database.yml for rendering using chef 11.10

I want to have an output(after rendering in chef) in database.yml, like below:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: <%= ENV['diff_db_user'] || <username> %>
  password: <%= ENV['diff_db_password'] || <password> %>
  ...
```

In the above yaml, I expect the values `<username>` and `<password>` are substituted from `@node[:database][:username]` &  `@node[:database][:password]`

So, the reason I wanted to do this is, to use a different password just by setting the environment variable while running a rake job like db migration

So, I tried the above with using escaping the erb tag as mentioned in [How do I escape the ERB tag in ERB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-the-erb-tag-in-erb) but in the output yml I could see the value is not substituted, it just prints the variable itself

for example I had an erb like this:

```
default: &default
      adapter: mysql2
      username: <%%= ENV['diff_db_user'] || @node[:database][:username] %>
      password: <%%= ENV['diff_db_password'] || @node[:database][:password] %>
      ...
```

The output I'm getting for it is:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  username: <%= ENV['diff_db_user'] || @node[:database][:username] %>
  password: <%= ENV['diff_db_password'] || @node[:database][:password] %>
  ...
```

So, wanted to know is there any other way for to get printed like the one I initially mentioned at the top, when using `template` in chef to render the erb to yml

Comment: What's the output you're having?

Comment: @SebastianPalma : I have edited the question and added the output I got

Answer (score 0):

You could add another item in `database.yml`

```
development_with_password:      
  adapter: mysql2
  username: 
  password:
```

and call it in your rake task e.g.

```
RAILS_ENV=development_with_password rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?! You need yo use nested `<% %>` tags, escaping the outer ones. Also don't forget the quotes.

```
username: <%%= ENV['diff_db_user'] || "<%= @node[:database][:username] %>" %>
password: <%%= ENV['diff_db_password'] || "<%= @node[:database][:password] %>" %>
```